# Dense subset of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

The question is:  Let $f: [a,b] \to [a,b]$ be a continuous bijection. Show that the set $\{p(f(x)) : p \text{ is a polynomial}\}$ is dense in $C([a,b])$.

I've broken it down by using the Weierstrass approximation theoren to look in the sup norm but I cannot get my inequalities to work out. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Update:

Here's an attempt at the problem.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given; let $f$ satisfy the assumptions given above. Let $g \in C([a,b])$ be arbitrary. Since $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, by the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, there exists a sequences of polynomials $(p_n)$ on $[a,b]$ which converges uniformly to $g$; that is, there exists $n_0 \geq 1$ for which $||g-p_n||_{\infty} < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq n_0$ for every $x \in [a,b]$.

Since $f$ is a continuous bijection from $[a,b]$ onto $[a,b]$, it's necessarily a homeomorphism; $f^{-1}$ is defined and continuous on $[a,b]$. To see this, let $U$ be an arbitrary closed subset of $[a,b]$. Then the inverse image of $U$ under $f^{-1}$ is precisely $f(U)$. However, $U$ is closed in $[a,b]$ so that it's compact, and the continuous image of compact is compact, and as such, is closed. Hence, $f^{-1}$ is a continuous function.

Let $h(x) = (g \circ f^{-1})(x)$. Since $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are onto, given any $y \in [a,b]$, $f^{-1}(y) = x$ for any $x \in [a,b]$. Now observe that, if $y = f(x)$,

$$
||p_n(f(x)) - g(x)||_{\infty} = ||p_n(g(x)) - h(g(x))||_{\infty} = ||p_n(y) - h(y)||_{\infty} < \epsilon.
$$

I'm not so sure about that last few lines; I'm a bit confused there.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If it's a bijection, all of $[a,b]$ is hit by $f(x)$, so $p(f(x))$ can be written as any $p(x)$ with $x \in [a,b]$.

So, use weierstrass then to complete it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will post an attempt above. Any feedback would be great!